# Relation between $\eta$ and $\omega^L_1$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ordinal-numbers

I posted this question on MSE (link: [Eventual Writability (general)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403361)) about 10 days ago. The current version of this question is a highly abridged version of the one posted there. Let's write "accidentally writable" and "eventually writable" as AW and EW respectively. See definition-3.10 (page-8) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06101) for the definitions. So we have the notions of: (i) AW-real (ii) Sup of AW-ordinal (iii) EW-real (iv) Sup of EW-ordinals. Let's simply use $AW$ and $EW$ to denote (i) and (iii) respectively. Let's use the symbols $\mathcal{A}$ and $\eta$ for the ordinals in (ii) and (iv) respectively.

**Short Version:**

> Why can't we set a variable whose value stablizes to $\omega^L_1$ (never to be changed again). And, in that case, then why can't we set a variable whose value stablizes to $\eta$ itself?

**Long Version:**

For the rest of the post I use $\omega_1$ to mean $\omega^L_1$. For the rest of the question "code for $\alpha$" simply means "well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ (in suitably encoded form) with order-type $\alpha$". We assume the access to an onto function $f:Ord \rightarrow AW$. That is, we have a program which when given any arbitrary input $x$ will halt and return a real that belongs to $AW$. Essentially, $f(x)$ corresponds to the "$x$-th time" an AW-real appears on the output (for a program that enumerates all elements of $AW$).

This [outline](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CeNdN87plOcmfYRJgzpdowZ3rLnjXtB2) might make it easier to understand what I am trying to say (in what follows). $\eta$ must be countable. But let's try to analyze this in a bit of detail. Because we have $\mathcal{A}=\omega_1$ there exists a variable which eventually settles to a value $\omega_1$ (and never changes after that). Setting-up such a variable (let's call it $v$) in a program isn't difficult. Initially set $v:=\omega$. Then go through $range(f)$ while waiting for code of $\omega$ to appear. Once it appears the command $v:=v+1$ is triggered. But this is also true in general. If, at any point, we have $v$ equal to $\alpha<\omega_1$, then go through $range(f)$ while waiting for code of $\alpha$ to appear. Once again this triggers the command $v:=v+1$.

One thing in last paragraph is that the value of $v$ is only ever increased. And because we have $\mathcal{A}=\omega_1$, the value of $v$ should stabilize to $\omega_1$, never to change again. Now we want another variable (let's call it $u$), which we want to stabilize to $\eta$ (and never changing again). Let's try to see how we can do that.

Let's denote $O_e(t)$ to mean that output of program with index $e \in \mathbb{N}$ at a time $t \in Ord$. Note that because we are talking about a program that starts from blank state, we can talk about a natural number as an index. Suppose at some point we had $v:=V$. We want to calculate the value of $u$ corresponding to the given value of $v$. Roughly speaking, for any time, the variable $u$ tries to "guess" $\eta$ in a local sense based on the current value of $v$. First, we wish to calculate a subset of ordinals, say $X$.

For all indexes $e \in \mathbb{N}$ we check whether there exists a value $x<V$ such that for all $x \leq y \leq V$ we have $O_e(x)=O_e(y)$. In-case this happens to be true check $O_e(V)$. If it happens that this contains a code for ordinal, then that ordinal belongs to $X$. Once we repeat this process for all indexes (and not just $e$), we have the set $X$. We can set the value of $u$ as the smallest ordinal not in $X$. We can also set the output to contain a code for the current value of $u$.

Finally let's try to observe what happens when $v:=\omega_1$. We have a combination of programs that do and do not stabilize permanently (that is, not just in limit $\omega_1$ but in actuality). Based on what was mentioned by MCarl in comments below the answer (in the MSE version of the question), all programs that do stabilize happen to do so in countable time. This is an important observation (generally speaking too but more so in the context of the current question). Because that would mean that when $v:=\omega_1$ we will be able to set $u$ as some value $\geq \eta$. Based on what is mentioned in last paragraph, we can also set the output to contain a code for the current value of $u$.

Comment: Your question is much too long and rambling. Can you edit to focus it on the main point?

Comment: You already answered **part-(A)** in first-half of your answer (meaning its answer should be in positive given your answer). Whatever is under the heading **part-(B)** specifically, it isn't that long I think (about 700 words or so).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins To add some further clarity, I think I will edit the question (most likely within a day) and upload a document which illustrates the basic structure of what I wrote under the heading **(B)** (that is, using informal program-like language). This should only be 20--30 lines or so and would make, what I wrote, easier to follow. In particular, it would be easier to follow that the behaviour of $u$ and output cells (due to alterations) on limits shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I have edited to add link to a basic sketch of few lines (as I mentioned in above post), under the heading **(B)**.  Even though it is just a rough sketch, hopefully it makes it easier to understand the idea that I have tried to describe in the few paragraphs that follow (under the given heading).

Comment: Your question will get a much better reception if you edit it, severely, for length. Currently, the post is a confusing mess. You've got part (A), then long part (A), part (B), etc., and in the middle of part (B), you say you've come to your "main question" and make a statement in bold type, but this is not even a question. I stopped reading part way through and just tried to guess what you were asking.  Less is more.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Edited to make it as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, which have improved the question. I have posted an updated answer, which I think gets at the issue you want.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for answering the question. I have added an optional point (in-case you find it interesting) in the edit. Is there an easy explanation for it? Anyway, I will try to think about it more precisely, and as I mentioned, possibly formulate it as a separate question (in-case I think it can be made precise).

Comment: Deleting previous comment and re-writing it for better clarity. "Quite roughly speaking, in the "EDIT:" I am thinking something similar to the idea of oracle programs with access to instruction of form $U:=Halt(v)$. Here $v$ is a usual ordinal variable. The instruction would give us a $U \subseteq \omega$ which describes which (ordinary) program indexes with just one parameter (which is current value of $v$) and no input halt. I am thinking whether the halting times of these oracle programs (or those similar to these) should be of concern or not."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me assume that you are concerned with ordinal time Turing
machines, using a tape of order type Ord.

My first observation is that the accidentally writable reals are
exactly the constructible reals.

**Theorem.** The OTM accidentally writable reals are exactly the
constructible reals, that is, the reals in $\mathbb{R}^L$.

**Proof.** The forward inclusion holds because all the OTM
computations can be undertaken inside $L$, and so whatever it is
that appears on the tape at any moment for them will necessarily be
in $L$. So every accidentally writable real is in $L$.

Conversely, we use the fact that the machines are able to simulate
the constructibility hierarchy. With a suitable choice of finitely
many ordinal parameters, the machines can construct a code for any
desired level of the $L_\alpha$ hierarchy and pick out the code for
any particular constructible set. In particular, with suitable
parameters, one can produce any given constructible real on the
tape. And now the point is that we can design a program that
systematically does this for all possible choice of ordinal
parameters. The universal algorithm will simply iteratively
increase a master ordinal, interpreting it as a code for a finite
tuple of ordinals, and carry out the construction that far. So
every particular constructible real will appear on the tape during
this universal procedure. $\Box$

In particular, the supremum of the OTM accidentally writable reals
will be exactly $\omega_1^L$.

Meanwhile, there are only countably-in-$L$ many programs and
therefore only countably many eventually writable reals, since each
one can be associated with the program giving rise to it. So
$\eta<\omega_1^L$.

The rest of your question appears to concern an algorithm that will
in part somehow store the value of $\omega_1^L$. Let us discuss how
this can be done. Since this is a machine model with only a tape
and no registers to store the value in, let me assume that you
intend to place a special mark at position $\omega_1^L$ on the
tape, in such a way that you can recognized that it has been so
marked. Let us say that position $\alpha$ on the tape is
*eventually markable* if there is an algorithm that eventually
places a $1$ at position $\alpha$, followed by a certain unique
finite pattern of marks, which eventually does not appear anywhere
else on the tape. If our tape allows a bigger alphabet, we could
say more simply that $\alpha$ is eventually markable if there is an
algorithm that (on empty input) eventually stabilizes with a red
check mark on position $\alpha$ and no other red check marks. Or we
can think of the special finite pattern as the red check mark.

**Theorem.** The ordinal $\omega_1^L$ is eventually markable.

**Proof.** The ordinal $\omega_1^L$ is the least ordinal that is
never coded by any real in $L$. So we can simply search for an
ordinal that will pass that test. We gradually consider ordinal
positions in turn. For every ordinal, we temporarily place a red
check mark at it, until we find a real coding it (this uses the
count-through algorithm to count to the position coded by any
relation coded with a real). When an ordinal is revealed as
countable in this way, then we move on to the next ordinal, erasing
the previous red mark and placing the next one. At limits of these
stages, the head will be in a position at the supremum of the
previous red marks. And so we will eventually place a red mark at
$\omega_1^L$, never afterward to change it. So $\omega_1^L$ is
eventually markable. $\Box$

The next part of your algorithm is to look at the eventually
writable reals that stabilize in time $\omega_1^L$, by using
simulations that proceed up to that red mark. This seems right to
me. More generally:

**Theorem.** If $\alpha$ is eventually markable, then the supremum
of the ordinals coded by reals that stabilize in time $\alpha$ is
eventually writable.

**Proof.** Consider the program that eventually marks $\alpha$. At
each stage, this algorithm is giving us a putative copy $\alpha_0$
of $\alpha$, which is eventually correct. For each $\alpha_0$ that
appears during the computation, let us run a simulation of all
programs on empty input, running them for $\alpha_0$ many steps. We
can arrange to inspect this computation to see if the output had
stabilized before $\alpha_0$, and in this way, we can compute a
list of all the reals that are
eventually-in-time-$\alpha_0$-writable. We can then check which
code a well-order, and then write down a real coding the supremum
of these ordinals. If at any moment, the red check mark changes,
then we start completely over with the new $\alpha_0$. Eventually,
$\alpha_0$ will be $\alpha$ itself, and we will stabilize on a real
coding the supremum of the eventually-in-time-$\alpha$-writable
ordinals, as desired. $\Box$

In particular, if we use $\alpha=\omega_1^L$, then we will
eventually write a real coding the supremum of the ordinals coded
by an eventually-in-time-$\omega_1^L$-writable real. It seems to me
that ultimately, the algorithm you are proposing is writing down
exactly the supremum of the
eventually-in-time-$\omega_1^L$-writable ordinals, and this is
strictly less than $\eta$.

In particular, it follows from what we've said so far that
eventually writable reals do not stabilize in time $\omega_1^L$.

**Corollary.** Not all algorithms producing eventually writable reals stabilize in time $\omega_1^L$.

But actually, it is a bit easier to see that there are computations
whose first $\omega$ cells eventually stabilize, but not by any
stage before $\omega_1^L$. To see this, consider the algorithm that
is eventually marking position $\omega_1^L$. Do not write on the
first $\omega$ many cells, except when you change the red check
mark, and then flash a $1$ and then $0$ on the first cell. This
algorithm will eventually stabilize with its red check mark at
position $\omega_1^L$, after which time it will no longer flash
anything in the first $\omega$ cells. So this is an algorithm that
writes an eventually writable real, but it does not stabilize
before time $\omega_1^L$.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken a brief look only, but this seems quite related to the question. One brief question before I take a detailed look. Are you saying that the comment (on MSE): *"OK, so you are asking for the supremum of what is usually called the "stabilization times". All stabilization times are countable and in fact, their supremum is again $\eta$"* has a mistake? [you can find it just below the answer given on MSE thread]

Comment: Because that would go against what you have written: "In particular, it follows from what we've said so far that eventually writable reals do not stabilize in time $\omega^L_1$."

Comment: I am saying that there are algorithms whose first $\omega$ many cells stabilize, but not at any countable stage. One can see this easily: compute the theory of $L_\alpha$ as $\alpha$ increases, and flash a cell whenever $L_\alpha$ thinks $\omega_1$ does not exist. This will flash unboundedly often for $\alpha<\omega_1^L$, but after that, it will stop flashing.

Comment: *"I am saying that there are algorithms whose first $\omega$ many cells stabilize, but not at any countable stage."* OK this seems to go against the comment that I quoted above (from MSE thread) ......... unless I happen to missing something obvious.

Comment: At any rate, thanks for your answer. I will try to read it carefully. Since it is closely related to what I asked, I am upvoting it. I will also try to think about $\omega^L_1$-stabilization issue independently (to understand it better).

Comment: A few observations. If we denote the supremum of stabilization times as $\mathcal{S}$ and if we have $\mathcal{S}>\omega^L_1$ then there are two things: (i) It must have countable cofinality. (ii) It must be admissible. Also, I agree with your last paragraph. Though one question is that whether the intention of the quoted comment (regarding stabilization times) was only with those outputs that produce a code for an ordinal or not. But I am being speculative here.

Comment: The point being that something like $\omega^{CK}_{\omega_1+1}$ (taking $\omega_1=\omega^L_1$?) doesn't have the properties mentioned in the previous paragraph, so then $\mathcal{S}$ has to be different and bigger.

Comment: Another thing is that your last paragraph is ofc correct. But it produces a real which has already been produced (via stabilization at countable time). I am not sure whether it matters or not, but I thought it is worth pointing out (and, in this sense, it might be interesting thinking in terms of "smallest" stabilization time for a given real).

Comment: The supremum of the stabilization times, it seems to me, must be the first 2-stable ordinal, the first ordinal $\alpha$ with $L_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_2} L$. If my thinking is correct, this is uncountable in $L$, precisely because $\omega_1^L$ is the least ordinal not seen as countable in $L$, which is a $\forall\exists$ property. This is a much stronger property than that mentioned by Merlin Carl, namely, merely of having the right $\forall\exists$ theory.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this very well (of course). Will it be admissible (it must be I think). Will it have countable cofinality? And how small it would be compared to something like $\aleph^L_{\omega}$ (assuming this terminology makes sense).

Comment: It will be much larger than $\aleph_\omega^L$, since the existence of each $\aleph_n^L$ is $\exists\forall$ expressible: "there exists a finite sequence of $n$ limit ordinals, such that there is no function collapsing one of them to the previous." And yes, it will be admissible for similar reasons.

Comment: *"If my thinking is correct, this is uncountable in $L$,....."* I don't know what that means precisely so my comment might be off. But shouldn't it be easy to give an (increasing) $\omega$-sequence for the sup of stabilization times (say $\mathcal{S}$) just based on appropriate parameters? (but it would require $\mathcal{S}$ itself as a parameter too though)

Comment: Yes, it obviously has countable cofinality.

Comment: Note: Merlin Carl has retracted his claim on math.SE about the stabilization times being countable, and he said he agrees with my argument about it.

Comment: OK that's good. Initially I thought that $\omega^L_1$ stabilization would lead to $\eta_0<\eta$ (with $\eta_0$ itself having strong closure properties). But after the comment, I assumed it to be correct naturally (since it was from an expert). Anyway, what do you think about the (last) comment I posted under the question. Would it be a suitable separate question? I don't think there would be that much interest generally though. So if you aren't interested enough, I won't be posting it as a separate question.

Comment: Your comment is related to ordinal register machines, and you seem to be describing some mixture of ordinal tape+register machines. I don't find that a compelling model, given that we have the other models, and they are known to be equi-powerful in various senses. If you want to use ordinal registers, use a register machine. If you want to use tapes, use a tape machine. The marking method on the tape seems to simulate whatever you want from a register, and so I don't find it desirable to change the underlying model.

Comment: Regarding what I wrote in earlier deleted comments, that's was mostly related to explicit implementation (and doesn't change anything theoretically ofc). Regarding what I wrote in the last comment (below question): I think it shouldn't be difficult to formulate an equivalent oracle machine with just tapes. I just worded it this way because it was easier to write in less number of words (in comments). Anyway, if you aren't interested enough, I won't be posting it as a separate question (since generally, the interest doesn't seem to be that high).

Comment: Well, certainly the oracle concept is natural, and people have studied it. I don't understand what the question is that you might have, but if you do ask it, it should be a separate question.

Comment: @SSequence More generally, using a class of ordinals $S$ as an oracle, the writable reals are the ones in $Δ_{1,S}^{L[S]}$, the eventually writable reals are the ones in $Δ_{2,S}^{L[S]}$, and the accidentally writable reals are the ones in $L[S]$. (Also, in place of reals, one can use sets of ordinals if the formula complexity is for equality rather than membership.)  If $S=∅$, the supremum of stabilization times for eventually writable reals is the least $L$-cardinal $δ$ such that $L_δ$ has the right $Σ_2^L$ theory.  This is a large $L$-cardinal, but below the least $δ$ with $L_δ ≺_{Σ_2} L$.

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky Thanks for the response. What you wrote is a bit beyond my level, but it makes "some" sense to me that the notions you mentioned would be captured by appropriate quantifications. Though I think I do understand well-enough that why the supremum of stabilization would be an ordinal of the form $\omega^L_\alpha$ (obviously a far stronger condition than admissibility, which I mentioned in comments above).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I have been thinking about a more specific notion than I mentioned in the question (more specific than the notion of "markable") and have understood a few things about it. What I wrote in the (current) edit is only partially relevant (I didn't modify the question again because I generally prefer to limit no. of modifications to avoid bumping). If I do find a question related to that notion that I think might be interesting to analyze than I might post it sometime as sort of a follow-up to this question (but it isn't necessary that I will post a follow-up question though).

Comment: One of the sentences in second-last comment above should be: "Though I think I do understand well-enough that why the supremum of stabilization **times** would be an ordinal of the form $\omega^L_\alpha$." Anyway, I will stop bothering with comments. I might ping upon posting a follow-up question.

Comment: How large is the supremum $\beta$ of stabilization times of OTMs with no oracles? Is $\beta$ equal to the least ordinal $\delta$ such that $L_{\delta}$ has the right $\Sigma_2^L$ theory? Or $\beta$ is equal to the least ordinal $\delta$ such that $L_{\delta} \prec_{\Sigma_2} L$?